# restrict partitioning of gemfire cache region to specific number of nodes

Tags: java, gemfire

I am using gemfire peer to peer set up for caching across different processes. For one region, I want to restrict partitioning to only 2/3 processes instead of across all processes. This is in order to reduce computational and network overhead which outweighs benefits from parallelism. Is there a way to specify this in gemfire configs?

Alternatively, I will need to set up separate processes for that region alone. This seems more cumbersome as it will require specifying all other regions as well with partition size 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you are configuring your cluster using gfsh, you can use server groups to achieve this.

When you start a server, you can assign it to a list of groups. Then when you create a region, you can tell gfsh to only create that region on servers with a given group.

```
gfsh> start server --name=server_with_data --group=datastore
gfsh> start server --name=server_without_data --group=accessor
```

Creates the region only on server_with_data

```
gfsh> create region --name=region --type=PARTITION --group=datastore
```

Create a proxy on server_without_data to access the region. No data is stored on server_without_data.

```
gfsh> create region --name=region --type=PARTITION_PROXY --group=accessor
```